How can I get rancid butter?
Well, the question is plain and clear, "How can I get rancid butter?".
But it is also a little odd, so have to give a little background information:
Sometimes, I feel an urge for sweet rice pudding, but recently I had no milk in the fridge, so I used water+butter. It tasted even better. Now I have tried this again, and it had a strange taste. Not bad, but strange. On the second helping, it tasted even slightly fruity and pleasant.
The only reason I can think of is that the butter (had been in the fridge for well over one year) had gone slightly rancid.
So, how can I check by getting some rancid butter?
Stepping into the nearest grocery store and asking "can I have some of your rancid butter?" carries a health risk, if the shopkeeper can run faster than me.

Rancidification is simply caused by the oxidation of the butterfat. If you want to “make” rancid butter, just leave it exposed on the counter (covered with cloth, if you’re worried about insects) for several days to a couple of weeks, depending on how rancid you want it.
I would not describe the taste of rancid butter as “fruity”, but rather as “cheesy” or “musky”. It’s possible that the butter you used had absorbed volatile fat-soluble aromas from other food (though if it were uncovered enough for that, I would also expect some degree of rancidity).

I had thought of that, even of cutting the butter into small slices to optimize surface to volume. But as you suspect, it could be some other aromas. How to be sure?

Well, for starters, by testing this one to rule it out.

The funky flavour of rancid butter is mainly due to Butyric acid, which is released from the butyrate containing triglycerides by oxidation. It's also one of the main scent compounds in parmesan and vomit. Cultured butter is also a thing; made from fermented cream, so should be tasty.'

Well, I guess I'll have to put some butter out of the fridge, cut to have a high surface-to-volume ratio and packed in a way that oxygen can get to it but insects can not. Funny experiment. I feel young again :-) .

I had a new dish with butter out of the fridge for about 4 days. The taste is strange but I am not sure if it is the same taste as previously (maybe the chemistry is too complex to be reduced to butyric acid. I guess I have to get some pure butyric acid to be sure.
